# How to customize Ant table rowselection

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I used Ant table to show some information.

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-architecture-lsb85?file=/src/index.js

I want to customize the position of the checkbox for row selection.
In this application, you can see the header in the following order of checkbox, Name, Age, Address but I want to swap checkbox and Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add checkbox columns and customize render and titleRender of it to checkbox and then handle the events. if you incounter performance issue you have to add some memoization on columns or evenet handlers.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Table, Button, Checkbox } from "antd";

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`
  });
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedRowKeys: [], // Check here to configure the default column
      loading: false,
      allChecked: false
    };

    this.columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name"
      },
      {
        dataIndex: "checked",
        title: () => {
          return (
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.allChecked}
              onChange={(e) => this.selectAll(e)}
            ></Checkbox>
          );
        },
        render: (text, rec, index) => {
          return (
            <Checkbox
              checked={
                this.state.selectedRowKeys.includes(rec.key) ||
                this.state.allChecked
              }
              onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, rec)}
            ></Checkbox>
          );
        }
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age"
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address"
      }
    ];
  }

  start = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // ajax request after empty completing
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        selectedRowKeys: [],
        loading: false
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  onChange = (e, rec) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        selectedRowKeys: [...state.selectedRowKeys, rec.key]
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        selectedRowKeys: [
          ...state.selectedRowKeys.filter((item) => item !== rec.key)
        ]
      }));
    }
  };

  selectAll = (e) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        allChecked: true
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        allChecked: false
      }));
    }
  };

  onSelectChange = (selectedRowKeys) => {
    console.log("selectedRowKeys changed: ", selectedRowKeys);
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, selectedRowKeys } = this.state;

    const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={this.start}
            disabled={!hasSelected}
            loading={loading}
          >
            Reload
          </Button>
          <span style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
            {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ""}
          </span>
        </div>
        <Table columns={this.columns} dataSource={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```